# apache syslog-ng error logs and access logs

Tags: apache, apache2, syslog

I am trying to send all my apache logs to syslog-ng(on remote machine) which in turn writes to a file.

so I configure syslog-ng this way

```
source s_apache {
      unix-stream("/var/log/apache_log.socket" max-connections(512) keep-alive(yes));
};
filter f_apache { match("error"); };
destination df_custom { file("/var/log/custom.log"); };
log {
        source(s_apache);
        filter(f_apache);
        destination(df_custom);
};
```

and add the following line to apache2.conf

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t 'apache'  -u /var/log/apache_log.socket"
```

but only logs being written to "/var/log/custom.log" are

```
[Mon Jul 13 17:24:36 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

and

```
[Mon Jul 13 17:26:11 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I want all logs to be sent to custom.log.....
Please help me.... where  am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you this link:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html
Here you can learn about log on apache.
If you want all log on syslog-ng, you must configure also access logs with CustomLog directive.

Regards,
Lorenzo.

Comment: ok....but I am not receiving all the error logs atleast.....
I deliberately tried to access some file which does n't exist thru some php application which is served by apache......those logs are going to standard apache error log file...i.e., /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and i found that the the ErrorLog and CustomLog settings were getting overwritten by /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

After commenting out those, it worked !

Or you can just put these settings in < virtualhost > if you want to log only specific domain calls

Regards
rane